# Reduce all columns of data.frame to one long vector

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

Probably quite a basic question, but can't seem to figure this out by myself.

I have a data.frame like this:

```
 df <- data.frame(X1=1:4,X2=5:8,X3=9:12)
```

I would like to create one long vector from all columns, that, for the example, would look as following:

```
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `data.frame` is a special type of `list`, so to get what you want, you can just use:

```
unlist(df, use.names = FALSE)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

```
> stack(df)[,1]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know the stack function before